# How to mock a service without using TestBed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking, components, testbed

I'd like to write some unit tests for my component without touching the external template. But I don't know how to mock a service that my component depends on.

`my-component.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {

    constructor(public service: AnotherService) {}

}
```

`my-component.spec.ts`

```
let component: MyComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
    myComponent = new MyComponent(null);
});
```

`another.service.ts`

```
@Injectable()
export class AnotherService {
    toto: string;
}
```

That works but instead of `null` I want to mock `AnotherService`, so i created a mock service:

```
class AnotherServiceStub {
    toto: string
}
```

and

```
myComponent = new MyComponent(<AnotherService> new AnotherServiceStub());
```

But with **ActivatedRoute** for example,

```
component = new MyComponent(<ActivatedRoute> {});
```

doesn't work. Typescript asked me to add all attributes of the ActivatedRoute class into my mock like *url*, *params*, *queryParams*, etc. How can i avoid that ?

Comment: `myComponent = new MyComponent({ toto: 'something' });`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks but it doesn't work because i use Typescript, that checks the type of the parameter.

Comment: If your mock has the same signature it will work. It's the same as injecting mocks through the test bed's providers. Could you give a less abstract example?

Comment: Fortunately, it's not TS who defines types but you. You can cheat it to accept everything you need, `new MyComponent(<AnotherService>{ toto: 'something' })` or even `new MyComponent(<AnotherService><any<{ toto: 'something' })`.

Comment: @estus yes, <AnotherService>{ toto: 'something' } works, thank you. But for example, as i updated my question, <ActivatedRoute> {}, the Typescript asks me to add all params of the ActivatedRoute class like: url, params, queryParams, etc. into my mock. How can i avoid that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service mocks that fully conform to the interface of original class can be provided as is:

```
myComponent = new MyComponent(stub);
```

If a mock partially conforms to the interface and doesn't pass type checking, [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) can be used:

```
myComponent = new MyComponent(<AnotherService>stub);
```

When types don't match at all, double assertion can be used:

```
myComponent = new MyComponent(<AnotherService><any>stub);
```